What are those chat features that not well-known
Recently, SEJPM wrote about a nice feature in the chat about a chat feature;

FYI: If you write [so] in a comment or here in chat it will auto-expand to Stack Overflow. Similar rules apply for [<site-name-in-url.se>]

so you can write [so] to get a link for the Stackoverflow, or [cryptography.se] for a link to our site.

How does it work exactly?
Are there some other nice features like this?


They are not just for chat, they are useful all over the site, see: [crypto.se] gives [crypto.se] here too :) I've created a more crypto specific page here on Cryptography Meta.

These are so-called magic links; they work in comments but a subset also works in chat.
Chat has more hidden features; some of them are documented here: What Easter Eggs do the chat sites have?

Thanks Glorfindel! I created a Crypto specific page for the smart links. Very useful tool to have.
